# Media Element Audio Source Node How to Play

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webkit, web-audio-api

So I am having a problem where I am trying to create a web-audio source node from a  tag. The Code Looks Like this:

```
OBJECT.musicContext= new webkitAudioContext();  
OBJECT.audio = new Audio();
OBJECT.audio.src = self.file;
OBJECT.source = OBJECT.musicContext.createMediaElementSource(OBJECT.audio);

var analyser= OBJECT.musicContext.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize=1024;
OBJECT.analyser=analyser    

OBJECT.gain = self.musicContext.createGain();
OBJECT.gain.gain.value = .01    
OBJECT.source.connect(OBJECT.gain)
OBJECT.gain.connect(OBJECT.analyser)
OBJECT.analyser.connect(OBJECT.musicContext.destination)

OBJECT.play = function(){OBJECT.source.play();}
OBJECT.stop = function(){OBJECT.source.stop();}
```

The problem is with the last two lines. I can't seem to get the audio to play through the webkit audio context...

If I do

```
OBJECT.play = function(){OBJECT.audio.play();}
```

the sound will start playing, but not through the audio node (which makes sense)

I have also tried

```
OBJECT.play = function(){OBJECT.source.noteOn(0);}
OBJECT.stop = function(){OBJECT.source.noteOff(0);}
```

to no avail...

Any help or suggestions are greatly Appreciated, and thanks in advance for your time!

Isaac

EDIT: when console.logging OBJECT.source is claims that there are zero inputs and 1 output. Is this correct for a source node?

Comment: Also, you can only have **one** `AudioContext`, be sure you're not creating a new one every time.

Comment: Only have one, made sure of that. It still seems to be the linking of the audio to the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally, but don't know exactly what the issue was...

rather then using

```
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = self.file;
```

and connecting this,
I instead used

```
audio = document.querySelector('audio');
```

to select an element I had previously put into the page. I am not sure if this works simply because it gave it more time to load, or if there is something intrinsic to the API

Comment: Wanted to add as well that this is what seems to work in chrome canary, however when I checked it out in Chrome it acts differently...

Comment: ALSO this I think was what was the problem: crbug.com/112368 !

Answer (score 1):

You should try your page in Chrome as [Safari currently doesn't send the correct data to the Analyzer Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958158/why-isnt-safari-able-to-process-audio-from-a-mediaelementsourcenode). If you're using an `Audio()` object with the Web Audio API then you should be able to control the playback with it instead of using `.noteOn()/.noteOff()`.

Here's the test case: http://screamingrobots.com/misc/safariaudiobug/

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for the response I've been using chrome for testing, but I never knew that about safari so its great to know! I'm starting to think there may be a more fundamental problem in my code tho, because even when I control it via the <audio> element, all the data returns 0 for every frequency. If I can't figure out whats wrong, I'll def come back and accept this answer, because it is the most helpful!