# Firefox 25 and AudioContext createJavaScriptNote not a function

Tags: html, firefox, web, web-audio-api

Firefox 25 says to bring Web Audio but an important functions seems to be missing - createJavaScriptNode.

I'm trying to build a analyser but I get the error in console that createJavaScriptNode is not a function.

Demo - http://jsbin.com/olugOri/3/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using `createScriptProcessor` instead. Firefox is still not getting correct values, but at least that error is no longer present.

Demo - http://jsbin.com/olugOri/4/edit

**Edit**: <sup>(more visibility for the important discussion in the comments)</sup>

---

### Firefox *does* support `MediaElementSource` if the media adheres to the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), however there is no error produced by Firefox when attempting to use media from a remote origin.

The *specification* is not really *specific* about it <sup>(pun intended)</sup>, but I've been told that this is an intended behavior, and the issue is actually with Chrome… It's the Blink implementations (Chrome, Opera) that [need to be updated to require CORS](http://twitter.com/jsantell/status/396753990412562432).

### [MediaElementSource Node and Cross-Origin Media Resources](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2013JulSep/0219.html):

> `From: Robert O'Callahan <robert@ocallahan.org>`
>   `Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 16:30:00 +1200`
>   `To: "public-audio@w3.org" <public-audio@w3.org>`
>
> HTML media elements can play media resources from any origin. When an
>   element plays a media resource from an origin different from the page's
>   origin, we must prevent page script from being able to read the contents of
>   the media (e.g. extract video frames or audio samples). In particular we
>   should prevent ScriptProcessorNodes from getting access to the media's
>   audio samples. We should also information about samples leaking in other
>   ways (e.g. timing channel attacks). Currently the Web Audio spec says
>   nothing about this.
>
> I think we should solve this by preventing any non-same-origin data from
>   entering Web Audio. That will minimize the attack surface and the impact on
>   Web Audio.
>
> **My proposal is to make MediaElementAudioSourceNode convert data coming from
>   a non-same origin stream to silence.**

If this proposal makes it into spec it will be nearly impossible for a developer to even realize why his `MediaElementSource` is not working. As it stands right now, calling `createMediaElementSource()` on an `<audio>` element in [Firefox 26 actually **stops** the `<audio>` controls from working at all](http://jsfiddle.net/9eGSp/1/) and **throws no errors**.

What dangerous things can you do with the audio/video data from a remote origin? The general idea is that without applying the Same-Origin Policy to a `MediaElementSource` node, some malicious javascript could access media that only the user should have access to (session, vpn, local server, network drives) and send its contents—or some representation of it—to an attacker.

The HTML5 media elements don't have these restrictions by default. You can include remote media across all browsers by using the `<audio>`, `<img>`, or `<video>` elements. It's only when you want to manipulate or extract the data from these remote resources that the Same-Origin Policy comes into play.

> [It's] for the same reason that you cannot dump image data cross-origin via `<canvas>`: media may contain sensitive information and therefore allowing rogue sites to dump and re-route content is a security issue. - [@nmaier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484441/nmaier)

Comment: `createJavaScriptNode` is a deprecated method (replaced by `createScriptProcessor`), much in the same fashion of `noteOn` being replaced by `start`. The values produced by this should be the same as webkit implementations, if not, be sure to file a bug!

Comment: @jsantell neither [Firefox 27 or Safari 7 are able to process audio data from `MediaElementSource`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958158/why-arent-safari-or-firefox-able-to-process-audio-data-from-mediaelementsource). Chrome (Blink) is the only browser that fully supports the Web Audio API right now.

Comment: ahhh, that was an issue over a year ago with Safari :[ https://github.com/jsantell/web-audio-api-bugs/tree/master/safari/MediaElement-to-JSNode  I'll make the appropriate bug for Firefox -- thanks!

Comment: actually, the above test case works for me in FF25 and FF28 (and replacing the deprecated APIs, webkit prefix, etc), looks like they uplifted the changes!

Comment: @jsantell Firefox does seem to support `MediaElementSource`, but only if the audio resource is from the same origin. It should also work if the server hosting the audio sets the correct CORS headers. I'm not sure I understand why they decided to do this. What dangerous things can you do with the audio data from a remote origin? And if that is per-spec, why does Chrome allow it?

Comment: @idbehold I'd assume you have to obey same-origin/CORS for the same reason that you cannot dump image data cross-origin via `<canvas>`: media may contain sensitive information and therefore allowing rogue sites to dump and re-route content is a security issue.

Comment: @nmaier I'd really like to see a proof-of-concept as to how a remote `MediaElementSource` could be abused. And it should be easy to test since both Chrome and Opera currently allow it.

Comment: @idbehold Breaking audio-captchas by abusing visitors computing power? Dumping data of private video conferencing recordings that the attacker has no access to, but the visitor does (has a session, vpn, whatever)

Comment: @nmaier that's still all dependent on the `<audio>` or `<video>` tag having access to the media. And if that's an issue, why hasn't anyone brought this to the attention of the Chrome team? Why hasn't anyone abused this yet?

Comment: According to the w3 list, Blink implementations need to update to require CORS: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2013JulSep/0219.html https://twitter.com/jsantell/status/396753990412562432

Comment: @jsantell Firefox doesn't throw any errors, and according to that w3 thread the proposal is to "convert data coming from
a non-same origin stream to silence". That doesn't seem helpful to the developer. At the very least it should throw an error in the same way that an XHR to a remote origin throws an error in the console.