# createMediaElementSource method of Web Audio API in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio, web-audio-api

According to the [Mozilla's WebAudio API Rollout](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAudio_API_Rollout_Status), WebAudio should be available in the Firefox 25.0.1.  Yet, I cannot get `createMediaElementSource` to work on Firefox but it works fine in Chrome.  Here is simplified version of the code:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var el = document.getElementById('audio');
// Breaks in Firefox.  Remove these 2 lines and audio plays in Firefox
var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(el);
sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
```

Here is a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcoslin/Jb4LN/

If you hit play in the Fiddle result using Chrome, the audio plays.  The music does not start in Firefox.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180550/firefox-webaudio-createmediaelementsource-not-working) without answer.

Comment: check this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708561/firefox-25-and-audiocontext-createjavascriptnote-not-a-function

Comment: @Dileepstanley indeed it is caused by Same-Origin Policy.  Post the comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to the same origin policy mentioned in last comment. For testing your code i have downloded the music files and tested with a server where i have the html code, it works well with fx 25.0.1

Here is the link :http://www.alianetwork.it/fx/