# Connecting MediaElementAudioSourceNode to AudioContext.destination doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

[Here's a fiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/f02nzgzp/). Basically, whenever the [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) method of an `AudioContext` object is called, the output of the audio element is re-routed into the returned `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`. This is all fine and according to spec; however, when I then try to reconnect the output to the speakers (using the [`destination`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/destination) of the `AudioContext`), nothing happens.

Am I missing something obvious here? Maybe it has to do with cross-domain audio files? I just couldn't find any information on the topic on Google, and didn't see a note of it in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/).

Code from the fiddle is:

```
var a = new Audio();
a.src = "http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3";
a.controls = true;
a.loop = true;
a.autoplay = true;
document.body.appendChild(a);

var ctx = new AudioContext();


// PROBLEM HERE
var shouldBreak = true;
var src;
if (shouldBreak) {
    // this one stops playback
    // it should redirect output from audio element to the MediaElementAudioSourceNode
    // but src.connect(ctx.destination) does not fix it
    src = ctx.createMediaElementSource(a);
    src.connect(ctx.destination);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [Web Audio API requires that the audio adhere to the Same-Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708561/firefox-25-and-audiocontext-createjavascriptnote-not-a-function/19710142#19710142). If the audio you're attempting to play is not from the same origin then the appropriate Access-Control headers are required. The [resource in your example](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3) does not have the required headers.

[image]